# NGRX Store selector without subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors

I'm using Angular (with typescript) and I'd like to retrieve a value from the NGRX store without using subscription.
If I do like this:

```
this.store.select(selectCardNickname)
```

it returns an Observable and I need to subscribe to that to get the value. I know there is the async pipe which could do that, but I need this value inside my typescript component, not in the html, because when I get this value I have to call a service which is gonna call my backend (using this parameter as payload).

This is the selector:

```
export const selectCardNickname = createSelector(selectProdTypeTabs, (tabs) => tabs.settings.value.cardNickname);
```

What can I do to solve that?

Comment: Whats wrong with subscribing it inside the onInit function and then populating another variable with the value?

Answer (score 0):

Using `store.select` will always create a subscription, there is no way to read the state using a synchronous method.
You can also let the effect handle this, as shown in https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#using-a-selector

Comment: I would like to add that the synchronous API existed in the earlier versions of NgRx but was **intentionally removed** in order to enforce reactive approach.